# Erro na sintaxe do script no R

Tags: r, script

tod@s bem? Estimo que sim

Por gentileza, não consigo avançar ao escrever esse comando:

```
flt <- filter(grade.ac,st_contains(ac,grade.ac,sparse = (FALSE))
```

O R informa: "unmatched opening bracket "(" ...

Por gentileza, solicito se possível uma orientação para superar esse detalhe, muito grato!

Answer (score 1):

Faltou você fechar um parênteses, você abriu 3 e fechou só 2.

```
flt <- filter(grade.ac,st_contains(ac,grade.ac,sparse = (FALSE)))
```

Comment: Muito grato, Letícia...